# Angular HttpClient doesn't actually convert to an object

Tags: angular5, angular-httpclient

I have a simple class defined in Angular with some properties, and then I get the results via an Angular 4 HttpClient typed `get`.

```js
getQuestions(): Observable<EhsAssessmentQuestion[]> {
    this.http.get<EhsAssessmentQuestion[]>(....);
}
```

and then I use it like so:

```
       this.ehsAssessmentService
             .getQuestions()
             .subscribe((data: EhsAssessmentQuestion[]) => {
                 if (data[0] instanceof EhsAssessmentQuestion) {
                     console.info("Yes!");
                 }
```

I'm basically just getting back a javascript object, not my EhsAssessmentQuestion class.  What do I need to do in order to make it come through as the right type?

Comment: maybe because you are not mentiong the type in the response

Comment: I am, see the edited question.  The formatting was off on the original post.

Comment: I am referring to `data`.

Comment: Tried that too, based on @Hamed answer.  Still not working.

Comment: I edited the question to explicitly say an "Angular 4 HttpClient typed get".  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you get returned from the observable is `Observable<Response>` and not `Observable<EhsAssessmentQuestion[]>`. You should handle the mapping yourself:

```
 return this.http.get(url)
  .map(res => { 
    return res.json().results.map(item => { 
      return new EhsAssessmentQuestion( 
          item.firstProperty,
          item.secondProperty,
          ...
      );
    });
```

Comment: That was true in Angular 3, but with the HttpClient added in 4 the typing is supposed to work.  https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b

Comment: Well, try it first. According to (https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/) this is still actual.

Comment: That's not using the Angular 4 HttpClient.  Notice how there is no casting to a type.  The "mapped" object from HttpClient doesn't not contain a json() call.  I'm getting back the actual JSON objects already.

Comment: You should state in the question if you want to make it work in a particular way, otherwise people (like me) will use time to answer, and it turns out to be useless.